# Grouping multiple values for same key from a text file to form single key-value pair

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk

First, if there is a better title for this question, I am all ears!

Is there a better way of doing this?

I have a data file `input.txt` in this format:

```
field1=value1
field2=value2
field3=value3
.
.
.
field1=value4
field2=value5
field3=value6
```

and so on ... and would like to end up with:

```
field1,value1 value4 ... valueM
field2,value2 value5 ... valueN
field3,value3 value6 ... valueO
```

What I've tried:

1. Generate unique keys: `cat input.txt |awk -F"=" '{print $2}' |sort -u > data_key`
2. Loop over rows in `data_key`

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> file=input.txt
> keys=`cat data_key`
>
> for value in $keys
> do
>   output=`cat $file |grep $value |awk -F"=" '{print $2}' |tr -s '[:space:]' '[ *]' `
>   echo $value, $output
> done
> ```

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. Your way does not even output the correct answer.

Comment: LOL ... ok ... ? Do tell! ... (-:

Comment: Actually, I would be much interested in hearing why you think this does not give the correct answer. I get the right output in my testing.

Comment: When I run it, I only see `value1,value1`, but no `field` in the result.

Comment: Most odd. The above script gives the same results as your and cravoori's solutions. I am on Mac OS 10.6 and 10.7. Either way, thank you both for some pretty neat solutions, and teaching me  something new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below awk-based solution should work. This uses associative arrays keyed by field names. Values are concatenated as they are encountered.

```
awk -F'=' '{z[$1]=z[$1]" "$2} END{for(i in z){print(i","z[i])}}' file_name.txt
```

Comment: Nice! Could you please explain `z[$1]=z[$1]" "$2` ...? Are you population an array `z` with values of `$2`?

Comment: @KM., yes, z represents an associative array with keys that are populated from field1, field2 etc. When a specific key is encountered on a line, the value stored within the array for this key is concatenated with a space and the newly found value.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution. It hashes the fields, each field is associated with an array of values. The order of output lines is random, though.

```
perl -e 'while (<>) {
             chomp;
             ($f, $v) = split /=/, $_, 2;
             push @{ $h{$f} }, $v;
         }
         print "$_,@{ $h{$_} }\n" for keys %h;
    ' input.txt
```

Comment: Cool! Could you elaborate on line `($f, $v) = split /=/, $_, 2;` I'm unclear on what the `2` is ... ? The rest I sorta get.

Comment: 2 is the number of parts you want to get. It means `field7=value_containig_=` will not split the value on `=`.

Comment: just changing to `for sort keys %h` gives it *some* order

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"=" '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2;}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i];}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
field1=value1
field2=value2
field3=value3
field1=value4
field2=value5
field3=value6
> awk -F"=" '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2;}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i];}' temp
field1 ,value1,value4
field2 ,value2,value5
field3 ,value3,value6
>
```